# Creating Web Secure Proxy in GCP - Certificate Issue

Tags: ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, certificate-authority, self-signed-certificate, gcp

I am trying to configure GCP Secure Web Proxy https://cloud.google.com/secure-web-proxy/docs/overview.
The proxy is under IP: 10.10.0.16. Besides that, it has a local DNS Zone proxy.carecode.lan that resolves to 10.10.0.16.

Executing this `curl -x https://proxy.carecode.lan:443 https://globo.com -v --proxy-insecure`, works.

On executing: `curl -x https://proxy.carecode.lan:443 https://globo.com -v`, I got:

```
*   Trying 10.10.0.16:443...
* Connected to proxy.carecode.lan (10.10.0.16) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

It points me that the problem is caused by self-signed certificate.
I am noob on that, but I have followed these steps: `https://community.workspot.com/gcp-150/setting-up-gcp-secure-web-proxy-1088`.

I have created a certified authority as below:
[image]

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            29:fb:16:5c:42:76:de:03:a6:a5:73:2d:3f:26:c2:a9:06:d7:66:23
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = proxy.carecode.lan
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 13 02:36:18 2024 GMT
            Not After : Mar 13 02:36:18 2025 GMT
        Subject: CN = proxy.carecode.lan
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e5:af:38:07:eb:37:a6:68:a1:aa:11:4e:f2:6f:
                    fb:87:d1:51:46:36:70:b1:87:9e:4d:81:4b:ae:8e:
                    15:8e:6e:bb:58:b8:24:31:31:7b:86:3b:6a:ea:f8:
                    b3:c9:34:0c:d0:0a:d5:34:fa:48:1d:ad:17:87:38:
                    e8:30:ee:72:93:a9:8c:9b:78:e0:df:32:e6:89:f3:
                    fa:4b:72:f5:26:d1:01:33:ed:6d:58:75:11:74:55:
                    93:7c:c4:85:53:15:70:d4:f9:9f:1d:5b:8d:27:32:
                    0a:8c:72:d9:cf:5a:37:a4:b7:69:a2:42:89:5a:ce:
                    dd:69:f9:aa:a2:82:57:69:29:08:df:37:4b:16:a3:
                    fe:20:fb:c4:bd:72:70:62:3e:a4:d8:8a:96:d5:7e:
                    43:66:54:b2:96:7b:d0:36:cc:92:b7:36:6d:f8:cb:
                    2e:83:89:bb:d4:ff:84:52:b3:2f:39:75:44:d8:f4:
                    d8:bb:b1:f5:cd:6d:6c:cb:e6:18:6a:c3:ae:81:b8:
                    db:30:63:dd:1e:e6:51:83:26:1f:52:94:88:47:9f:
                    75:1c:70:c8:e8:60:98:34:b6:66:7b:0d:15:9a:e0:
                    3f:bf:90:2d:0f:34:13:ba:13:0b:37:e5:37:d7:a6:
                    a2:90:08:b8:5a:ac:cc:43:67:b4:58:24:11:f4:d1:
                    39:af
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                96:AC:19:0D:FA:CB:7F:1E:DA:76:33:90:C3:2F:2C:F0:88:72:D0:D8
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:96:AC:19:0D:FA:CB:7F:1E:DA:76:33:90:C3:2F:2C:F0:88:72:D0:D8

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:proxy.carecode.lan
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         31:4e:79:26:ec:84:a6:26:f2:c3:c1:84:03:8c:43:13:a1:4c:
         3d:a8:ae:d0:78:d0:8e:83:2a:e9:a4:38:8c:26:ba:9c:88:d5:
         ab:68:2a:25:58:3c:61:59:6d:f6:3b:06:35:be:8c:58:0c:5d:
         e8:85:dd:6b:ee:d2:bd:62:33:5f:c3:24:cf:bc:3e:c7:52:86:
         ab:3d:2c:e5:f8:74:72:ff:f2:40:20:29:38:ce:f0:22:1f:c4:
         8d:01:83:14:df:9e:8e:87:d0:63:86:28:c8:5c:c1:d8:05:64:
         de:be:52:df:6a:51:96:f8:bd:d1:e6:d3:24:9e:25:ad:08:a5:
         79:74:e4:f8:6e:6b:2f:35:32:83:5f:55:6c:32:93:d1:c0:00:
         49:7e:3c:4f:87:90:3f:95:ea:87:2c:12:e5:75:e1:18:7e:50:
         e9:2c:76:49:1b:0b:37:ea:24:03:cc:fc:ff:78:4d:ff:82:5e:
         24:f6:44:0b:7e:15:66:80:b2:bb:8c:a6:5e:4d:45:e7:fd:5f:
         5f:10:71:48:28:ea:7c:78:09:a1:11:cb:c6:af:49:dd:87:31:
         c9:d2:bb:a1:67:d4:b5:43:63:f9:2e:32:cc:9c:f9:f3:36:fb:
         e8:fc:48:1e:77:08:85:ea:71:2c:26:b5:31:c7:34:d4:a7:5e:
         5b:bf:29:0d
```

Does anyone have a clue on that?

Comment: In order to avoid `self-signed certificate` warning, you need to generate a **private key** and **certificate signing request** (CSR), the CSR should be signed by a well known Certificate Authority(CA) (whose root certificate is known to the browser so that it can trust the certificate provided by the server) to get the certificate.

Comment: You can also refer to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service/docs/create-certificate) to create the certificate using the console. After that upload the certificate and the key to the certificate manager and use the certificate to the **SWP (Secure Web Proxy)** gateway.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.